# How can I grab a GuildID without having to use a command

Tags: python, sql, discord.py

I am trying to make a multi-server bot that has a logging feature. I have a database which can take in Log Channel IDs, and I know how to select them, but in this instance (of a display name update) you can't just grab ctx.guild.id. So I am very confused on how I could do this. Would I be better off just using a .json file?

```py
    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        if before.display_name != after.display_name:
            logchannel = self.bot.guild.get_channel(db.field("SELECT LogChannel FROM guilds WHERE GuildID = ?", guild.id))
            embed = Embed(title="Member update", description="Nickname has been changed.", colour=after.colour, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

            fields = [("Before", before.display_name, False),
                      ("After", after.display_name, False)]

            for name, value, inline in fields:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)
            embed.set_image(url=before.avatar_url)
            await logchannel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use before.guild.id or after.guild.id